# Joomla Editor not working after restoring mysql database

Tags: mysql, centos, ext3, joomla

I've made a big mistake on one of my sites and **I've deleted accidentally several files** from our site's joomla directory. The database was Ok, so what I tried to do was to create a Joomla installation from scratch, and after having it working restoring the database through MySQL.

But there's a problem with this. After restoring the database I get all the content back (part of the images are gone, it's gonna be dificult to recover them on our server, CentOS on ext3 partition), but the big problem is that **when I try to edit some article, the editor doesn't work**. I've tried all the available editors I had (TinyMCE, JCE, XStandard Lite, TMEdit), but none of them work. TinyMCE at least shows something (here, [http://imgur.com/ltYkA](https://imgur.com/ltYkA) ), but I can't get this to work.

I don't know **if there is some module or component missing**: I can't remember exactly which modules I had installed, but.. could a database restore make this happen??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have something like Aptana Studio or Eclipse. What you want to do is set up your IDE to have a FTP connection with your website then so a sync with a new local joomla setup. This is suppose to compare date and time stamps of all files. It should tell you which files are missing and which are different. Skip the different ones but upload the missing ones.I have had this before and there were 8 files missing. What you also have to do once you have replaced the missing files is go into one of the config options and reset which editor to use. Sorry I can't remember much more detail but it was done about 8 months ago at 2 in the morning so long term storage wasn't working to well that night.

Comment: Well, my idea was more or less compare files from a working installation, but I have no experience with Aptana/Eclipse. Thanks for the idea, I'll try and will go as far as I can.

Comment: Well you can compare with a working site. Make sure they are both Joomla 1.5 or whatever version that they are. The Aptana or Eclicpse are just because they both have an FTP tool that will scan all the files and tell you what files are missing or different. If you can find a GUI FTP tool then use that. A database change shouldn't change an editor. The database mainly contains the articles that make up Joomla.

Comment: Problem solved. What we did was check every component of the Joomla installation was well installed. Some of them had missing files, so we just reinstalled every plugin-extension that we were using. The final step, though, was a bit tricky: we clean the administrator's cache on the Joomla control panel. That finally allowed us to recover the editor. Many thanks for your suggestions kingchris!

Comment: Always a pleasure. Glad my suggestions prompted you to find your own solution by digging around. Cheers